How can I make the background of this Python/Tk Treeview table all dark?
I'm preparing to write a user interface for a REST interface and I've never used Python/Tk before.  I've written a program which shows files in the current folder for now while I figure out the look of the UI.  Unfortunately I've got stuck trying to make the whole window Dark.  I have white patches showing around the table like so and I wondered if anyone knew how to make them dark?

The code looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def get_files_and_sizes():
    files = os.listdir('.')
    files_and_sizes = {}
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            size = os.path.getsize(file)
            files_and_sizes[file] = size
    return files_and_sizes

def display_details(file_name):
    details_window = tk.Toplevel()
    details_window.title("File Details")
    details_window.configure(background="#333333")

    label = ttk.Label(details_window, text="File Name: " + file_name, background="#333333", foreground="#CCCCCC")
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

    close_button = ttk.Button(details_window, text="Close", command=details_window.destroy, style="Dark.TButton")
    close_button.pack(pady=5)

def display_files_and_sizes():
    def refresh():
        # Clear the treeview
        for row in tree.get_children():
            tree.delete(row)
        # Refresh files and sizes
        files_and_sizes = get_files_and_sizes()
        index = 1
        for file, size in files_and_sizes.items():
            tree.insert("", index, text=str(index), values=(file, size))
            index += 1

    def close():
        root.destroy()

    def show_details():
        item = tree.selection()[0]
        file_name = tree.item(item, "values")[0]
        display_details(file_name)

    def sort_column(col, reverse):
        data = [(tree.set(child, col), child) for child in tree.get_children('')]
        data.sort(reverse=reverse)

        for index, (val, child) in enumerate(data):
            tree.move(child, '', index)

        tree.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_column(col, not reverse))

    files_and_sizes = get_files_and_sizes()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Files and Sizes")
    root.configure(background="#333333")
    root.geometry("1024x768")

    # Define style for columns
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Dark.Treeview.Heading", background="#666666", foreground="#CCCCCC", font=('Helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    style.configure("Dark.Treeview", background="#333333", foreground="#CCCCCC", font=('Helvetica', 10))
    style.configure("Blue.Treeview.Cell", foreground="#6FA1D3")

    # Define style for buttons
    style.configure("Dark.TButton", background="#444444", foreground="#CCCCCC")

    tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("File", "Size"), style="Dark.Treeview")
    tree.heading("#0", text="Index", anchor=tk.W, command=lambda: sort_column("#0", False))
    tree.heading("File", text="File", anchor=tk.W, command=lambda: sort_column("File", False))
    tree.heading("Size", text="Size (bytes)", anchor=tk.W, command=lambda: sort_column("Size", False))
    tree["show"] = "headings"  # Hide the default empty column at the beginning

    index = 1
    for file, size in files_and_sizes.items():
        tree.insert("", index, text=str(index), values=(file, size))
        index += 1

    # Set style for the first column cells
    tree.tag_configure("blue", foreground="#6FA1D3")

    for i in range(1, len(files_and_sizes) + 1):
        tree.tag_configure(str(i), foreground="#6FA1D3")

    tree.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    refresh_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Refresh", command=refresh, style="Dark.TButton")
    refresh_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

    close_button = ttk.Button(root, text="Close", command=close, style="Dark.TButton")
    close_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Right-click menu
    menu = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0, bg="#555555", fg="#CCCCCC")
    menu.add_command(label="Details", command=show_details)

    def popup(event):
        if tree.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "cell":
            menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    tree.bind("<Button-3>", popup)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    display_files_and_sizes()


In your example code I don't see a style.theme_use  and so on my machine I get a white tree background and undefined button colors. On the other hand you Toplevel window button seems to work!?

As other comment said, you need to try another theme and set fieldbackground option for "Dark.Treeview" style as well.
